# Making a prediction from a trained convolution network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Here is my `convolution` net that creates training data , then trains on this data using a single `convolution` with `relu` activation :

```
train_dataset = []
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
num_instances = 10

for i in range(num_instances) :
    image = []
    image_x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000).reshape((1 , 100, 10))
    train_dataset.append(image_x)

mu, sigma = 100, 0.80 # mean and standard deviation
for i in range(num_instances) :
    image = []
    image_x = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000).reshape((1 , 100, 10))
    train_dataset.append(image_x)

labels_1 = [1 for i in range(num_instances)]
labels_0 = [0 for i in range(num_instances)]

labels = labels_1 + labels_0

print(labels)

x2 = torch.tensor(train_dataset).float()
y2 = torch.tensor(labels).long()

my_train2 = data_utils.TensorDataset(x2, y2)
train_loader2 = data_utils.DataLoader(my_train2, batch_size=batch_size_value, shuffle=False)


import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms


# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
# device = 'cpu'

# Hyper parameters
num_epochs = 50
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 5
learning_rate = 0.001

# Convolutional neural network (two convolutional layers)
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=1):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.fc = nn.Linear(32*25*2, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

model = ConvNet(num_classes).to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train the model
total_step = len(train_loader2)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader2):
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if (i % 10) == 0:
            print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
                   .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss.item()))
```

To make a single prediction I use :

```
model(x2[10].unsqueeze_(0).cuda())
```

Which outputs :

```
tensor([[ 4.4880, -4.3128]], device='cuda:0')
```

Should this not return an image tensor of shape (100,10) of the prediction ?

Update : In order to perform a prediction I use :

```
torch.argmax(model(x2[2].unsqueeze_(0).cuda()), dim=1)
```

src : https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/argmax-with-pytorch/1528/11

`torch.argmax` in this context returns the position of the value that maximises the prediction.

Comment: No. The image, originally of dimension `(100, 10)` passes through all the layers that you've defined above `[Conv->BN->ReLU>MaxPool->Conv->BN->ReLU->Maxpool->Linear]`, with the output dimension of each layer changing according to the properties of each layer *(like maxpool `(2X2)` halves, ETC)*. Finally you get your output from the last `Linear` layer, which outputs a vector of dimension `num_classes`, which in your case is 2. And rightly so you get the output.

Comment: @Koustav please see question update.

Comment: Actually your doubt is a bit unclear to me. I mean, torch.argmax() over the prediction will return the index of the max value. In the above case it would be the index of 4.4880. Are you getting or expecting something different than this? Then please mention it.

Comment: @Koustav My understanding is that the index of the max value is the prediction. So if I had 3 classes instead of two the indices of the possible predictions are 0,1,2 instead of 0,1. Can you inform how 4.4880 is derived, it's a result of training the model ?

Comment: Hey! Please allow me to suggest you to have an understanding of how image classification with CNN works, before diving into the code. If you need I can provide you with some starter's material. I feel that part need to be brushed up a bit.


And to answer your query, the number `4.4880` is derived by performing a series of *sum-of-products* as your input gets passed through the consecutive layers, with the *learned weights* (while training) of your hidden units. And yes, the index of the max-value is the class-label index of your prediction.

Comment: @Koustav yes! please post any start material you recommend. I'm attempting to learn and implement in parallel.

Comment: Basics of CNN :
(1) CS231n (the Holy Grail):http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/
(2) Medium post: https://medium.com/technologymadeeasy/the-best-explanation-of-convolutional-neural-networks-on-the-internet-fbb8b1ad5df8
(3) PyTorch example: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [Koustav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965539/making-a-prediction-from-a-trained-convolution-network#comment90881190_51965539) your net is not "fully convolutional": although you have two `nn.Conv2d` layers, you still have a "fully-connected" (aka `nn.Linear`) layer on top, which outputs only 2 dimensional (`num_classes`) output tensor.

More specifically, your net expects a 1x100x10 input (single channel, 100 by 10 pixels image).
After `self.layer1` you have a 16x50x5 tensor (16 channels from the convolution, spatial dimensions reduced by max pooling layer).
After `self.layer2` you have a 32x25x2 tensor (32 channels from the convolution, spatial dimensions reduced by another max pooling layer).
Finally, your fully connected `self.fc` `nn.Linear` layer takes the entire `32*25*2` dimensional input tensor and produces a `num_classes` output from the entire input.